# Why does += of a list within a Python tuple raise TypeError but modify the list anyway?

Tags: python

I just came across something that was quite strange.

```
>>> t = ([],)
>>> t[0].append('hello')
>>> t
(['hello'],)
>>> t[0] += ['world']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> t
(['hello', 'world'],)
```

Why does it raise `TypeError` and yet change the `list` inside the `tuple`?

Comment: I guess you'd have to see how `+=` is actually implemented. It seems it does not actually create a new list, it changes the list in-place, that's the `+` part. Then you have the assignment, but since tuples are immutable, this is not allowed.

Comment: @FelixKling  += works similar to append(), i.e the id() of the list remains same.

Comment: Also note that to be able to hash a tuple, all of it's component parts must also be hashable.

Comment: This is in [the official FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works), with a very nice explanation. There's also a [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue11562) which explains why it isn't a bug.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As I started mentioning in comment, `+=` actually modifies the list *in-place* and then tries to assign the result to the first position in the tuple. From the [data model documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types):

> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (+=, -=, *=, /=, //=, %=, **=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, |=). These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self).

`+=` is therefore equivalent to:

```
t[0].extend(['world']);
t[0] = t[0];
```

So modifying the list in-place is not problem (1. step), since lists are mutable, but assigning the result back to the tuple is not valid (2. step), and that's where the error is thrown.

Comment: And just to clarify, the existing list did get concatenated with the list from the RHS, but the assignment to the tuple failed, but it's reference to the list object still remained intact. That's why you see the list updated and the tuple raising a `TypeError`.

Comment: Got it. It makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @Felix Kling but even after += the id() of the list remains same, but  the id() of a list changes if we modify it like this,for eg x[0]=x[0]+['list'] , where x is a list of lists.

Comment: @Ashwini: Only `+=` is supposed to modify the list *in-place* (no new list). If you have the normal `+` operator, implementations most likely will return a new instance of the class (a new list). Try `x[0] += ['list']`. Or what is your point? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: +1 @FelixKling I understood your point.

Answer (score 8):

This is on http://bugs.python.org/issue11562.